# Proportional Transformation

Tags: .net, winforms, fullscreen, window-resize

I have a form where user can add and position charts and controls for a presentation like app. User can then change it to FullScreen mode, How do I change the size and position of controls to keep a relative position and size?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I resize my panels when resizing the main form in a winforms application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/174355/how-do-i-resize-my-panels-when-resizing-the-main-form-in-a-winforms-application)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store the control sizes / positions as percentages of form width, and use these percentages when the form is resized to programmatically size the controls - that's a simple enough solution that should work nicely.

Comment: Made it, stored controls controls position size and positions as pencentage and on ResizeEnd event I set their sizes/pos.

Simple but elegant at all :P